# Install Chrome Linux from PXE boot

Tags: boot, system-installation, livecd, pxe, chrome-os

I've got a PXE boot server from which I can boot a selection of LIVE CD's. Mostly different Ubuntu distributions.

Setting it up for ubuntu was relatively easy. I have copied the caspar directory from the live cd to the tftp directory and put everything else into an nfs directory.

I've created a submenu for ubuntu that looks like this:

```
LABEL 2
        MENU LABEL Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot (64-bit)
        KERNEL ubuntu/11.10/amd64/vmlinuz
        APPEND root=/dev/nfs boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.2:/srv/install/ubuntu/11.10/amd64 initrd=ubuntu/11.10/amd64/initrd.lz quiet splash --
        TEXT HELP
        Boot the Ubuntu 11.10 Oneiric Ocelot x64 Live CD
        ENDTEXT
LABEL 3
    MENU LABEL xubuntu 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin (32-bit)
    KERNEL ubuntu/12.04/x86/vmlinuz
    APPEND root=/dev/nfs boot=casper netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.2:/srv/install/xubuntu/12.04/x86 initrd=ubuntu/12.04/x86/initrd.lz quiet splash --
    TEXT HELP
    Boot the XUbuntu 12.04 Precise Pangolin x86 Live CD
    ENDTEX
```

etc.

Now I would like to do the same for chrome linux x86. I've downloaded the cd image and mounted it under `~/chromelinux`, but there is no casper so I am stuck now.

Have no clue what to do next.

On that CD mount I have the following files:

```
.
├── boot
│   ├── grub
│   │   └── mbrid
│   └── i386
│       └── loader
│           ├── 16x16.fnt
│           ├── af.hlp
│           ├── af.tr
│           ├── animations [error opening dir]
│           ├── ar.hlp
│           ├── ar.tr
│           ├── back.jpg
│           ├── bg.tr
│           ├── bootlogo
│           ├── branding [error opening dir]
│           ├── ca.hlp
│           ├── ca.tr
│           ├── chain.c32
│           ├── cs.hlp
│           ├── cs.tr
│           ├── da.hlp
│           ├── da.tr
│           ├── de.hlp
│           ├── de.tr
│           ├── el.hlp
│           ├── el.tr
│           ├── en.hlp
│           ├── en.tlk
│           ├── en.tr
│           ├── es.hlp
│           ├── es.tr
│           ├── et.hlp
│           ├── et.tr
│           ├── fi.hlp
│           ├── fi.tr
│           ├── fr.hlp
│           ├── fr.tr
│           ├── gfxboot.c32
│           ├── gfxboot.cfg
│           ├── gl.tr
│           ├── gu.hlp
│           ├── gu.tr
│           ├── hapysuse.mod
│           ├── hi.tr
│           ├── hr.hlp
│           ├── hr.tr
│           ├── hu.hlp
│           ├── hu.tr
│           ├── id.tr
│           ├── initrd
│           ├── isolinux.bin
│           ├── isolinux.cfg
│           ├── isolinux.msg
│           ├── it.hlp
│           ├── it.tr
│           ├── ja.hlp
│           ├── ja.tr
│           ├── ka.tr
│           ├── ko.hlp
│           ├── ko.tr
│           ├── kroete.dat
│           ├── ky.hlp
│           ├── ky.tr
│           ├── linux
│           ├── lt.hlp
│           ├── lt.tr
│           ├── mboot.c32
│           ├── memtest
│           ├── mr.hlp
│           ├── mr.tr
│           ├── nb.hlp
│           ├── nb.tr
│           ├── nl.hlp
│           ├── nl.tr
│           ├── pabout.txt
│           ├── pa.hlp
│           ├── panim_a.jpg
│           ├── panim.jpg
│           ├── pa.tr
│           ├── pback.jpg
│           ├── phead.jpg
│           ├── pl.hlp
│           ├── pl.tr
│           ├── pt_BR.hlp
│           ├── pt_BR.tr
│           ├── pt.hlp
│           ├── pt.tr
│           ├── ro.hlp
│           ├── ro.tr
│           ├── ru.hlp
│           ├── ru.tr
│           ├── sk.hlp
│           ├── sk.tr
│           ├── sl.tr
│           ├── sr.tr
│           ├── sv.hlp
│           ├── sv.tr
│           ├── ta.tr
│           ├── text.jpg
│           ├── tg.tr
│           ├── th.hlp
│           ├── th.tr
│           ├── timer_a.jpg
│           ├── tr.tr
│           ├── uk.hlp
│           ├── uk.tr
│           ├── wa.tr
│           ├── welcome.jpg
│           ├── xh.hlp
│           ├── xh.tr
│           ├── zh_CN.hlp
│           ├── zh_CN.tr
│           ├── zh_TW.hlp
│           ├── zh_TW.tr
│           └── zu.tr
├── Chrome_Linux-read-only.i686-2.1.1145
└── config.isoclient
```

The contents of `isolinux.cfg` are these:

```
default Chrome_Linux
implicit 1
display isolinux.msg
ui gfxboot bootlogo isolinux.msg
prompt   1
timeout  200
label Chrome_Linux
  kernel linux
  append initrd=initrd ramdisk_size=512000 ramdisk_blocksize=4096 splash=silent showopts 
label Failsafe_--_Chrome_Linux
  kernel linux
  append initrd=initrd ramdisk_size=512000 ramdisk_blocksize=4096 splash=silent showopts ide=nodma apm=off acpi=off noresume selinux=0 nosmp noapic maxcpus=0 edd=off

label harddisk
  localboot 0x80

label memtest
  kernel memtest
```

So how do I set this up so that computers on the network can boot to this "CD" and install the OS from this?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: Have a look at the isolinux.cfg (maybe gfxboot.cfg) and adjust everything accordingly. But please be aware if the initrd has no support for pxeboot/nfsroot things it will get complicated.

Comment: @UlrichDangel, thanks for the tip. Did I understand this correctly? I will use `MENU INCLUDE chromelinux/chromelinux.menu`. Copy `isolinux.cfg` there and add `netboot=nfs nfsroot=192.168.1.2:/srv/install/chromelinux/x86` to each append line in that file and hope that it will work or else suspect that NFS is not supported? If so please provide it as an answer here. Thank you.